# I am Trying to encrypt data from Source to Destination using Java but getting following Error message

Tags: java, exception

1)this method will perform file handling operation
this code also available in SCHAUM'S OUTlines
on page no 278.

```
  public void encrypt(String inFile,String outFile) throws Exception {

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

    String line = null;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(encrypted(line));
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

2.)  second block calling of method encrypt...
       `String inFile = "D:\Alice.txt";
        String outFile = "D:\Alice1.txt";

```
    Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor(key);

    try {
        encryptor.encrypt(inFile, outFile);      //HERE ERROR OCCURS
    }
    catch(IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("exception : " + exception);
    }
```

exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Alice.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

plz suggest me any other way to run this code.
thanks

Comment: Be careful with backslashes.  Try either `D:\\Alice.txt` or `D:/Alice.txt`  I assume that the file is actually present in the root of the specified drive.

Comment: This has nothing to do with encryption, removing tag.

Comment: a) does the file exist (I think you already checked this, but better know for sure)? b) OS?